# Meteor account enrollment

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I'm looking for a way to customize logins to allow for an administrator to provide a user with an account and a one-time-use temporary password (via email), that enables the user to log into a site (the user can't create an account on their own).

The first time the user logs in, they are instructed to change the temporary password given by the administrator.

I have accounts-ui and accounts-password working, but the user can create a new account at will.

If it matters, I plan to use Autoform and Iron Router for this.

I search the Meteor docs for "enroll", but the information is sparse IMO. Is there a fully working example somewhere to help me get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the usual way of creating an account, use Accounts.config:

> [forbidClientAccountCreation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config) Boolean
>
> Calls to createUser from the client will be rejected. In addition, if you are using accounts-ui, the "Create account" link will not be
>   available.

Then, instead of having a temporary password, I think you should [create the account](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) without password and then [use `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_sendenrollmentemail) to send the user an email to choose one.

> To create an account without a password on the server and still let
>   the user pick their own password, call createUser with the email
>   option and then call Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail. This will send the
>   user an email with a link to set their initial password.

So, something like that:

```
Accounts.config({forbidClientAccountCreation: true});

Meteor.methods({
  adminCreateAccount: function (accountAttributes) {
    if(Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().role == "admin") {
      var accountId = Accounts.createUser({
        'username': accountAttributes.username,
        'email': accountAttributes.emailAddress
      });
      Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(accountId);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer, this works and is exactly what I needed!  Sorry it took me a while to get back to this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

- let the admin create user (Accounts.createUser)
- add a marker ( eg `user.profile.changedInitialPwd`) which will be set when the user
  changed his pwd)
- use some verification logic to make sure, the user has changed his password before he is allowed to sign in

E.g.

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
  if (attempt.user && !attempt.user.profile.changedInitialPwd ) {
    console.log('Initial password not changed');
    return false; // the login is aborted
  }
  return true;
});
```